# What is a good library/framework + http webserver for I/O heavy application

Tags: io, webserver

I'm looking for a library or framework and webserver that can run applications in the given library/framework's language (I don't care which language) that has proven to be very effective and high concurrency I/O, both disk I/O and communicating with 3rd party services.

I've seen (and done some of my own) benchmarking that confirms servers/libraries like gevent perform incredibly well in the sterile hello world environments, in a real world scenario they struggle to provide useful throughput for just 50 or so concurrent connections with average response times running to 5 seconds or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it doesn't matter which language and which platform, my advice is to look at the nginx ( pronounced Engine-X) webserver. This webserver is extremely lean and as a result it's faster than apache ( and IIS )

The down side is that the configuration is a bit more complex.

Comment: I'm ok with complex config.  I've been aware of nginx for a while.  Is there any particular framework/language you would recommend that facilitates fast I/O?  That's where I'm more bound than pure number of requests that the server can handle.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider the node.js (Javascript server side). It's event/concurrency model has proven to be incredibly fast.

I have no personal experience with Erlang, but I hear that's a decent choice as well.

Comment: We benchmarked node and it's performance was slightly worse than gevent with much higher CPU overhead.

Comment: Hmm, you should write a blog post about it. This way you'd be giving Node.js a fair shot, as I'm sure the community would point out ways to improve your benchmarking methods using either Node.js or gevent.

Comment: I'll get round to it once we've finished all our testing.  I'm sure a lot of people would be interested in some tougher benchmarks than how fast X can serve "Hello World". AFAIK Node is great for 3rd party service I/O, if that was all we were doing it would be an easier choice, but we have a significant amount of disk I/O and it doesn't shine there.